# Thinking of O or 0 or O

Tags: logical-deduction

I am thinking of one thing.

It is either an ellipse (shape),

Or, it is the letter O

Or, it is the number 0

You can ask me one question and guess what the thing is.

I can only answer No,or sometime or always.

So what is it?

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate because it's easy to translate questions from the linked puzzle into questions here and vice versa.

Comment: Why is this a duplicate? It does not concern 1,2 or 3? Only O,0 and ellipse

Comment: @DeepakMahulikar:  Read the comment immediately above yours.

Comment: More broadly: [Guessing among three possibilities with a single question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/50798/19765)

Comment: @Deusovi. Isn't this just another puzzle of the same type? I can't see how you can use the questions from the linked puzzle here. This question is comparing a shape, a letter and a number so a purely mathematical question is not possible.

Comment: @Mads: You can just map them to 1, 2, and 3, then ask about their images under that map.

Comment: @Desusovi. Like "If an ellipse represents the number 1, the letter O represents the number 2 and the number zero represents 3 then ..."? I see. So if Deepak added a condition: "The question must concern the things in themselves. It is not allowed to let the things be represented by other things." or "The question cannot concern mathematics." the question would not be duplicate? I just personally enjoyed to think about the differences and similarities between an ellipse, O and 0 and believe it is a different excercise than the linked puzzle.

Answer (score 4):

I ask you -

> Can you find it in the upper right corner of the obverse face of a US $1 bill?
>  [image]
>
>  The text **always** contains an O (letter)
>  The serial number **sometimes** contains a 0 (digit)
>  That part of a dollar **never** contains an ellipse.

Having said that, I suspect this question is **too broad** ...  we'll probably see plenty of good answers.

Comment: Aren't Os ellipses and therefore the answer for ellipse would be "yes"?

Comment: @JonathanAllan Then the question devolves to "Is it an ellipse, an ellipse, or a zero?" at best, or "Is it an ellipse, an ellipse, or an ellipse?" at worst; allowing them to be considered equivalent breaks the question entirely.

Comment: Not necessarily, it just means we cannot use that precise nature to make our decision (and this possibly means it is nowhere near as broad as the 1,2,3 question).

Answer (score 2):

> Can you rotate it ninety degrees without altering it?

Because

> You can **always** rotate the letter O, **never** rotate the number 0, and **sometimes** rotate an ellipse (because all circles are also ellipses).

Comment: Is number 0 always an Oval? In all Fonts?

Comment: This is not correct for the letter O — it is usually not a perfect circle.